# extend json model with new attribute

Tags: jquery, json

Given  `model` is a json model that have a lot of key attribute mapping which return from a server, say `{name:"hello"}`,
how do I extend it with a new attribute key

```
attribute key: hello
attribute value: hello1
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's just a JavaScript object literal, can't you just say:

```
myJson['hello'] = 'hello1';
```

(assuming myJson is your variable holding the model.)

Calling `JSON.stringify()` on `myJson` should yield:

```
{ 
  'name': 'hello',
  'hello': 'hello1'
}
```

Comment: It's not a literal; it's an object.